# Can I repair a chain saw chain?

Tags: chainsaw

I have a chain saw (one of the ones for pruning trees) and the chain popped off.  I went to put it back on but one of the teeth is damaged on the part that slides along the arm of the chain saw.  It looks like it is only this single tooth that is causing the chain not to slide into the arm.  Is there anything I can do to repair the chain or am I going to have to buy a new one?

[image]

Comment: To avoid this in the future, make sure you oil and tighten the chain before each use if it's been a while.  And if you've been cutting for long enough to heat it up, maybe an hour or so, check and re-tighten the chain if necessary.

Comment: @BMitch - This is probably exactly what happened.  It was near the end of the job so I imagine things had loosened and the oil was low.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One of my dad's words of wisdom to me was "Don't mess around with chainsaws."  While he meant be careful when using them, I'd say it applies here.  While you could try to repair the chain, if it caused something to bind and caused kickback while sawing, the results could be disastrous.

And new chains are cheap compared to prosthetic limbs- $20-$30.  So do yourself a favor, throw the old chain away, and buy a new one.

Comment: There's a lot of fear in the post, but the point is correct: saw chains are neither expensive not repairable.

Comment: Didn't mean for it to be fear filled (the prosthetic comment was more tongue in cheek than anything.). That being said, a faulty chain on a chainsaw can be dangerous, and if you've ever had a saw catch you off guard and kick back, a small dose of fear is well placed.  My main point was that a faulty chain can put you in a dangerous situation, and even though it isn't highly likely, chains are so cheap that it is hardly worth the risk.

Comment: @MarkD I took your advice and bought a new chain.  Only $15 so definitely not worth taking any chances here.  Thanks again!

Comment: I keep 2 spare chains on hand, so I have no need to keep running a dull or damaged chain just to finish a job.

Comment: Chains can be fixed/sharpened shortened/extended by a qualified person. The danger is when the chain is loose or sticking like ops says. but yes +1 for get a new one and +1 for PUT OIL IN :)

Comment: @ppumkin : sharpening isn't that difficult ... they sell file guides that make it quite easy ... but for all other repairs, I'd say don't do it yourself.  (and I speak from the experience of someone who got slapped in the leg by a thrown chain; luckily, the guard caught it and took most of the energy, so it was only a scratch and some torn pants, rather than anything more serious)